# Is there a way to close Vim built in terminal with a keybinding?

Tags: vim

I created a keybinding in Vim to open a Terminal split window.

```
nnoremap <C-t> :terminal <CR>
```

I would like to modify this to close the any open terminal if I press again `<Ctrl+t>` but I can't get it to work. Any help please?

Thanks for your time

Edit: I tried with this, but it's not working, I actually don't know quite well how to do this in the first place:

```
nnoremap <C-t> if &filetype == 'bash' | then | :q | else | :terminal | endif
```

Comment: "I can't get it to work" What  did  you try?

Comment: I used an if statement but I can't really find how to check if a terminalis open in a window, and how to close it

Comment: Then show us that. SO is about programming Q/As after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following, or a modification of it:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-t> :call <SID>toggle_terminal()<CR>
function! s:toggle_terminal() abort
  let l:w = bufwinnr('term://.*/\d\+:bash') " find window having bash terminal
  if l:w > 0 " if found
    execute l:w . 'close'
  else 
    split term://bash " start a new bash terminal in a split
  endif
endfunction
```

Basically it looks for a bash terminal first, and then open a new one or close an existing one accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! It is a step forward, but when I press <C-t> again the terminal doesn't close. Do you know about something that could fix that?

Comment: In the terminal, when you press `C-t`, do you mean you are in the terminal mode or a normal mode? These two are different modes, both of which you can enter in a terminal buffer.

Comment: In normal mode, while editing the code, the terminal may get too much space so I would like to close it with the same button that I used to open it. Like NERDTree Toggle shortcut

Comment: @sicro Then you need a totally different one. I've updated the answer.